# Slow MySQL left join query

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 MySQL tables (shown as table_name:column_list):

```
tbl_product: id, name
tbl_sales: productid, date
tbl_impressions: productid, date
```

*tbl_products* stores available products, *tbl_sales* stores each sale of a product and *tbl_impressions* stores each impression of a product. I would like to find products that have been **sold, displayed, or both**. My attempted query for this is:

```
SELECT prod.name
FROM tbl_product prod
LEFT JOIN tbl_sales sales ON sales.productid=prod.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_impressions imp ON imp.productid=prod.id
WHERE (sales.productid IS NOT NULL) OR (imp.productid IS NOT NULL)
```

However, in my tests this query is extremely slow. What options do I have for improving it?

Comment: Are the `productid` field indexed on `tbl_sales` and `tbl_impressions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_product INNER JOIN tbl_sales ON id = productid
UNION
SELECT name FROM tbl_product INNER JOIN tbl_impressions ON id = productid
```

Comment: This was the fastest version by quite a margin. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use Index on `productid` and `id` fields in all these table. The JOIN will give performance if we have index on joining fields.

Answer (score 1):

Using `EXISTS` instead of your `LEFT JOIN`s should help.

```
SELECT prod.name
FROM tbl_product prod
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_sales sales WHERE sales.productid = prod.id )
   OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_impressions imp WHERE imp.productid = prod.id )
```

Make sure to add indexes on `tbl_sales.productid` and `tbl_impressions.productid`. <sub>(as others said)</sub>